# Closing ApplicationContext still not shutting down springboot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I've a spring-boot application where I'm starting Tomcat.

I want to shutdown the application when it has finished its operation.

I'm following this [blog](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-shutdown) to shut it down.

It prints log `Spring Container is destroyed!`, but I still have to press the stop button in IntelliJ to stop it.

Here is the `@SpringBootApplication`:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    MyService myService;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        myService.getResult();
        System.out.println("-------> 1");
        ((ConfigurableApplicationContext)context).close();
    }
}
```

**Logs:**

```
2019-11-06 00:51:57.018  INFO 26820 --- [           main] c.m.f.MyApplication  : Starting MyApplication on FTYUIN000171 with PID 26820 
2019-11-06 00:51:57.026  INFO 26820 --- [           main] c.m.f.MyApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-11-06 00:52:00.423  INFO 26820 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.hateoas.config.HateoasConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.hateoas.config.HateoasConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$74fff90c] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-11-06 00:52:02.282  INFO 26820 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 9090 (http)
2019-11-06 00:52:02.358  INFO 26820 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-11-06 00:52:02.359  INFO 26820 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.22]
2019-11-06 00:52:02.796  INFO 26820 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-11-06 00:52:02.796  INFO 26820 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 5304 ms
2019-11-06 00:52:08.093  INFO 26820 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-11-06 00:52:09.999  INFO 26820 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 9090 (http) with context path ''
2019-11-06 00:52:10.010  INFO 26820 --- [           main] c.m.f.MyApplication  : Started MyApplication in 14.216 seconds (JVM running for 42.337)
-------> 1
2019-11-06 00:53:31.833  INFO 26820 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
Spring Container is destroyed!
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>            
    </dependency>               
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20090211</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.4</version>
    </dependency>               
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.uuid</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-uuid-generator</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.0</version>
    </dependency>               
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.0</version>
    </dependency>   
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, Spring boot deploys web application to embedded Tomcat. So when you start Spring boot app, Tomcat will be started, and your web app will be deployed. When you close Spring context, only your web app stopped, Tomcat is still running, (thread, if there is any, is running as well).

So what you should do is completely kill your app by using `System.exit(0);`

Comment: Thanks. But that doesn't sound like a graceful shutdown.